# How to active tabs on windows by terminal? wmctrl doesn't have option available

Tags: terminal, window-manager, firefox, command

I'd like improve a script of mine that uses firefox to perform tasks. I need activate a window and a tab with a specific name. For example, the window name could be `Mozilla Firefox` and the tab `http://localhost/site.php`.

I can activate windows using `wmctrl -a`, but this doesn't work very well because all firefox windows could have `Mozilla Firefox` on its name, even the windows without tabs named `http://localhost/site.php`.

An example of what I need is: activate the tab `http://localhost/site.php` at the window `Mozilla Firefox`. I use linux and I would like a solution for this kind of system. Probably I will use shellscript (and OS commands) and python to improve the script, so solutions with them are welcome to me.

Comment: Are you aware of all the command line arguments Firefox comes with? `firefox --help`?

Comment: Tabs are managed internally by Firefox, they are not an OS-level like windows. `wmctrl` can't see tabs, you need to go through Firefox.

Comment: @jippie, I have read the man of firefox. No solution.

Comment: @Gilles, maybe not, but maybe we have a solution. If I need to go to firefox to do this, how can I do this using a shellscript that calls a javascript inside firefox?

Answer (score -1):

> /path/to/firefoxbinary -new-tab http://www.google.com

is what you want. There are other useful command line arguments available:

> /path/to/firefoxbinary --help

Comment: I was thinking about the `-no-remote` flag, which opens an entirely new firefox instance.

Comment: This will work to me if I close the previous window and create another one (using no-remote). But it isn't a good solution, the script will lose in performance and I don't know how to get the pid of the new firefox instance created.